# ios animation like emailing photo

Tags: ios, uiview, uiwindow, uianimation

I'm really curious as to how apple does this transition: If you go to a photo within the photos app, then try to send it in an email, you'll see this pretty cool transition where Apple grabs the image, slides up a modal email vc, then places the image into the message. Pretty cool.

Anyway, im wondering if anyone has any ideas as to how to do something like that. One way I'm thinking about doing it is to actually reproduce it, stick it on the UIWindow, then animate it that way. I'm actually kind of stumped as to how this could work. Any thoughts??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I actually got pretty close tonight with this (sample project up on [Github](https://github.com/CodaFi/PhotosAnimationDemo)).  It's a bit "Fake it to make it", but then again, so is the Photos app if you really watch the animation closely.  The values for the animation are hard coded in, but it's mostly for scale and move, which means this should work with pretty much any image (don't quote me on that).  The code is iOS 5+ for now because Xcode keeps yelling at me about deprecated modal presentation methods...

Comment: ya definitely think this is the way to do it. Haven't gotten around to cleaning it up but probably worth the checkmark anyway. Thanks! If anyone wants to elaborate further tho please go ahead . . .

Comment: Will be updating this periodically anyhow.